# Smali - Printing variable as string to console

Tags: android, console, smali

okay so i ahve been searching and trying trying to understand the smali code i have but i cannot get my head around it any help would be very apreciated...

so i have this code and i want to be able to print the .line 6 V2 in the .method private S()V to the console as a string..

how would i do this?? Thank You

CODE BELOW :

```
.method private S()V
.locals 5

.line 1
new-instance v0, Lcom/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient;

invoke-direct {v0}, Lcom/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient;-><init>()V

.line 2
new-instance v1, Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;

invoke-direct {v1}, Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;-><init>()V

.line 3
new-instance v2, Le/c/c/e;

invoke-direct {v2}, Le/c/c/e;-><init>()V

new-instance v3, Lcom/myfirstapp/util/Json;

invoke-direct {v3}, Lcom/myfirstapp/util/Json;-><init>()V

invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Le/c/c/e;->x(Ljava/lang/Object;)Le/c/c/j;

move-result-object v2

check-cast v2, Le/c/c/m;

const-string v3, "method_name"

const-string v4, "get_myuserinfo"

.line 4
invoke-virtual {v2, v3, v4}, Le/c/c/m;->q(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

.line 5
iget-object v3, p0, Lcom/myfirstapp/interfaces/LiveTvItemFragment;->y:Ljava/lang/String;

const-string v4, "cat_id"

invoke-virtual {v2, v4, v3}, Le/c/c/m;->q(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

.line 6
invoke-virtual {v2}, Le/c/c/j;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v2

invoke-static {v2}, Lcom/myfirstapp/util/Json;->toBase64(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v2

const-string v3, "data"

invoke-virtual {v1, v3, v2}, Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;->put(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

.line 7
sget-object v2, Lcom/myfirstapp/util/e;->b:Ljava/lang/String;

new-instance v3, Lcom/myfirstapp/interfaces/LiveTvItemFragment$a;

invoke-direct {v3, p0}, Lcom/myfirstapp/interfaces/LiveTvItemFragment$a;-><init>(Lcom/myfirstapp/interfaces/LiveTvItemFragment;)V

invoke-virtual {v0, v2, v1, v3}, Lcom/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient;->post(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestParams;Lcom/loopj/android/http/ResponseHandlerInterface;)Lcom/loopj/android/http/RequestHandle;

return-void
```

.end method

Comment: Starting with Smali is not an easy task. If you want to insert code the best way is to write a very small test app in AndroidStudio and add a method that contains just the call you want to add. Then compile it to APK the decompile it using apktool. The you can copy the call you need into the source code you have here. Just adapt the registers (e.g. v2) and if your code writes to a register make sure to use a register that is not needed later. BTW: If you just want to see v2 at run-time it may be easier to inject [Frida](https://frida.re) on a rooted device instead of modifying the whole app.

Comment: awsome thanks i had never thought of actually writing a test app lol... 

i was not changing the .locals number to add my new registers thanks you for your help :)